# curl upload all files in a directory with a single curl command?

Tags: bash, curl

I am looking to upload a multipart/form-data file upload. I working on a circleci job to auto deploy a couple files of a specific file type all in one go.

This solution works but it is making a seperate curl call for each file.

```
cd ~/project;find . -name "*.txt*" -type f -exec curl -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $bearertoken" -F "deployment-name=${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}" -F "deployment-source=circleci" -F "enable-duplicate-filtering=false" -F "deploy-changed-only=true" -F "{}=@{}" http:www.blah.com  \;
```

I am wondering if there is a way that I can build a file list of all the files in the directory and then use that variable in a single curl upload.

Comment: It depends on whether the script you're sending to allows multiple uploads.

Comment: Yes, it supports multiple files in a single update. For example it would work like this -F "./file1=@./file1.txt" -F "./file2=@./file2.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop to create an array of alternating `-F` and `filename=@filename`. Then substitute the array into the curl command.

```
files=()
while read -r filename; do
    files+=(-F "$filename=@$filename")
done < <(find . -name '*.txt' -type f)

curl -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $bearertoken" "${files[@]}" -F "deployment-name=${CIRCLE_SHA1:0:7}" -F "deployment-source=circleci" -F "enable-duplicate-filtering=false" -F "deploy-changed-only=true" "${files[@]}" http:www.blah.com
```

Comment: Surely there's an extra `$` in `"${$files[@]}"`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you. made some slight modifications to my scripts.

Comment: this script doesn't work

Comment: @b26 There was a typo that Charles Duffy noticed but I never fixed.