# upload all files with same extension using curl

Tags: linux, maven, curl, nexus3

I want to upload all `.jar` files in a directory to nexus repository manager.

I have tried :

`curl --upload-file $(find -name *.jar) nexus-host -u username:password`

This does not work.

Comment: very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466038/curl-upload-all-files-in-a-directory-with-a-single-curl-command)

Comment: Why using curl instead of Maven for that? What's the reason?